# Setup project is not registering the same on DEBUG mode than on RELEASE mode compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, com, setup-project

On Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project I've included the "Main Result of" several library assemblies (dll), some of them **COM-Visible**, (compiled and registered as COM visible). Some of these COM-visible assemblies depends on other non COM base libraries. Whole solution is Framework 2.0 oriented.

The generated installer was tested on a clean Windows 7 (x86), when compiled in DEBUG mode, ALL COM libraries are copied and registered as expected, the application runs; but when the same project is compiled in RELEASE mode the COM libraries are not registered properly and the caller application throws COM exception.

**After DEBUG is installed, I could replace the existing (debug) libraries using copy/paste on %ProgramFiles% with the release ones, and the application runs as expected.**

*Note: At this moment I cannot distinguish if the problem is on setup executable or at compiled libraries interfaces, (previous to package into the setup).*

How could I correct the setup project to perform the same registration steps in both (debug and release) modes, or how could I detect the differences betwwen debug and release installers? should I check the registry or setup properties?

all ideas will be appreciated,
Cristian.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138613/setup-project-uses-debug-dlls-when-in-release-configuration/35581957 will be helpful.