# Setup Project uses Debug dlls when in Release Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I can build a "debug" deployment package when Visual Studio 2010's solution configuration is set to "Debug".  But when I change it to "Release" and build my setup project, the resulting msi still packs the debug dlls.  Why might this be?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the [image: Configuration Manager] about your setup project ?

Comment: Yes.  I know that, by default, setup & deployment projects are not configured to build at the same time as other projects.  My normal workflow is to set the configuration, build the solution and then build the deployment project.  It made no differenece whether I built the deployment project at the same time or separately.  Anyway, I ended up creating a new deployment project, this time specifically targeting components from the "release" build.

Comment: Often developers add references to library dlls instead projects which makes the reference hard coded to debug or Release, instead adding reference to project which automatically detected from where to grab referenced dll. So make sure, when adding reference to a lib from other project, choose the project instead directly output assembly.

Comment: Which is exactly what I do.  The problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a bug. I'm observing the same behaviour in VS2013. Just close and reopen the solution to update the dependencies.